# How can I retrieve just the last two rows inserted in an SQLite database?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I want to retrieve the last 2 rows inserted into an SQLite database for display in a label.  What would be the proper SQLite statement to retrieve these rows?

Answer (score 2):

If you last inserted data has just inserted (maybe in the same method), you can use:

[last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

If you like to read the last insert data after, let's say a app re/start, then you need to do some ordering.

If you have a auto-incrementing id row, you can do the following

```
"SELECT * from your_table ORDER BY your_autoinc_id DESC LIMIT 2"
```